# Erro 500 ao adicionar redirecionamentos para erros 425 à 499

Tags: apache

Tenho um arquivo `.htdocs` onde nele tem vários redirecionamentos de erro (tem para todos os tipos de erro `HTTP`, e é tudo que tem no arquivo): `ErrorDocument 400 /PROJETOS/error.php?status=error_400` porem quando adiciono linhas respectivas a erros `HTTP 425` à `HTTP 499` dá erro interno de servidor `HTTP 500`. Alguém sabe o motivo?

**Versão:** Apache 2.4.10

Log:

```
[core:alert] [pid 5676:tid 1644] [client ::1:54077] C:/xampp/htdocs/PROJETOS/.htaccess: Unsupported HTTP response code 425
[Tue May 26 13:46:38.149363 2015] [core:alert] [pid 5676:tid 1644] [client ::1:54080] C:/xampp/htdocs/PROJETOS/.htaccess: Unsupported HTTP response code 450
[Tue May 26 13:46:45.820801 2015] [core:alert] [pid 5676:tid 1688] [client ::1:54082] C:/xampp/htdocs/PROJETOS/.htaccess: Unsupported HTTP response code 450
[Tue May 26 13:46:52.481182 2015] [core:alert] [pid 5676:tid 1668] [client ::1:54084] C:/xampp/htdocs/PROJETOS/.htaccess: Unsupported HTTP response code 499
```

Comment: Já verificou o [*Error Log*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html) por prováveis causas?

Comment: @qmechanik ao que parece o apache não reconhece estes códigos de resposta.

Comment: De fato esses códigos são inválidos, segundo [está lista de códigos do IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml).

Comment: @qmechanik o que faço com esta pergunta?

Comment: Se quiser mantenha ela, pode ser que apareça uma resposta ou alternativa para o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dito pelo usuário @qmechanik estes códigos são inválidos ou ainda não implementados como podem ver no site da [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml)(Internet Assigned Numbers Authority):

```
425 Unassigned  
426 Upgrade Required    [RFC7231, Section 6.5.15]
427 Unassigned
430 Unassigned
432-499 Unassigned
```